# Read InputStream just to the first ENTER?

Tags: java, inputstream

I have an Inputstream (the stuff what the user is typing into the consol, System.in.read();)

Now i want to put this InputStream later into a String it looks something like that:

```
    InputStream input = System.in;


    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    byte[] b = new byte[4096];
    for (int n; (n = input.read(b)) != -1;) {
        out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
    }

    System.out.println(out);
```

I know there are a lot of better ways. But i want to finish this one. The only Problem is with != -1 , it never happens. Whats the int for ENTER? So my for ends.

Thx!

Comment: Is the use of `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` allowed in this assignment?

Comment: yes it is. I tried buffered reader, but theres the same problem. I can say readLine() but it never ends...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally [CONTROL]+[D] would end input for your application, which should return you a -1 for your method call. Depending on the OS, you might want to try [ENTER] then [CONTROL]+[D] and [ENTER] again.

Answer (score 2):

this is about the standard way to do it

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: i know but i want to use the string as an inputstream and later i want to read this inputstream and put as a string...

Answer (score 0):

it should be one of 10 or 13 values depending on os.

Comment: according to [this aritcle](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t146788-how-do-i-detect-if-the-user-has-pressed-the-enter-key.html) you can't get it right